# How to set / shrink table row size in portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, tablerow

How do I set the table row width and size in portrait? I preferred how it looked in landscape view. Is there a way for me to shrink the "Component" table in portrait and increase the size for "marks", "demerit" and "notes"?
I tried adjusting the `layout_weight` , `layout_width` and `layout_size` but somehow I can't see the table header anymore.

**Lanscape View**
[image: Lanscape View]

**Portrait View**
[image: Portrait View]

**What I want to achieve in portrait**
[image]

**FragmentA.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="layout.fragmentA">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@color/btn_textcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur_marks"
        style="@style/marks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Markah:   / 18"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <!--Table header-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_component"
            style="@style/table_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Component"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_marks"
            style="@style/table_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Marks"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_demerits"
            style="@style/table_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/tableH_demerit"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_notes"
            style="@style/table_header"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Notes"/>
    </TableRow>

    <!--Component A1-->

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cA1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
            android:text="@string/cB1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mA1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_12"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/catatan"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">hellowWorld</string>
<string name="title_case_detail">Case Detail</string>
<string name="cB1">Kawalan suhu dan tempat mempamerkan makanan yang sesuai mengikut keadaan
    dan jenis makanan: \n
    - Suhu makanan panas: > 60 °C \n
    - Suhu makanan dingin: 1 °C hingga 4 °C \n
    - Suhu makanan sejuk beku: <= -18 °C
</string>
```

It would really help if it can look like the one in landscape view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give weight_sum to TableRow and equally distributed the weight to the child it will work fine

> Note: for child item, we should give `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#555"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur_marks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Markah:   / 18"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <!--Table header-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_component"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Component"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_marks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Marks"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_demerits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="tableH_demerit"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/th_notes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Notes"/>
    </TableRow>

    <!--Component A1-->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cA1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/cB1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mA1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="_12"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_a1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_a1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="catatan"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Using `weightSum` and setting `layout_width="0dp"` really did solve my problem.